# pfdbox different pdf versions, encoding, font types

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, pdf-generation, pdfbox

'the problem is that a can't read my own pdf files.'

I'm testing the pdfbox java toolbox for editing pdf files.
I have made some pdf files and all seem to be different for pdfbox.
SO with pdfbox I open a file, page by page, i read the text (if Tj or TJ) and replace it if needed. 
I have a template with text: "this file is made by [username]" 
and with my program i can replace [username] with the user from my db.

Now i have made pdf files from google docs (download as pdf) which creates emtpy lines in pdfbox with reading like this:

```
//this is an op with Tj
COSString previous = (COSString) tokens.get(j - 1);
String string = previous.getString();
```

than i created a pdf using libre office (on ubuntu) and now it is a TJ which needs this code:

```
COSArray previous = (COSArray) tokens.get(j - 1);
for (int k = 0; k < previous.size(); k++) {
    Object arrElement = previous.getObject(k);
    if (arrElement instanceof COSString) {
        COSString cosString = (COSString) arrElement;
        String string = cosString.getString();
    }
}
```

which will give me strange bloks.

When i use an windowx docx document (which i found in an email somewhere) and convert it using an online converter it also has TJ elements and works nicely (i see the text).

my question is: what is the difference between different pdf's (pdf version 1.3/1.4, font, encoding, more??). And more important what does pdfbox understands or how can i read the other files? is there some meta data? can i set the encoding/versin/font type in pdfbox?

thanks,

tibi

ps here my full (work in progress not so nice code):

```
package nl.tibi.pdfboxhelper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSArray;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSString;
import org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.COSVisitorException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFStreamParser;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.ContentStreamWriter;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumentCatalog;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumentInformation;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDMetadata;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.PDGraphicsState;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFOperator;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper;

/**
 * Hello world!
 */
public class PdfStringReplacer {

    /**
     * Locate a string in a PDF and replace it with a new string.
     * 
     * @param inputFile
     *            The PDF to open.
     * @param outputFile
     *            The PDF to write to.
     * @param strToFind
     *            The string to find in the PDF document.
     * @param message
     *            The message to write in the file.
     * @throws IOException
     *             If there is an error writing the data.
     * @throws COSVisitorException
     *             If there is an error writing the PDF.
     */
    public void replaceString(String inputFile, String outputFile, String strToFind, String message) throws IOException, COSVisitorException {
        // the document
        PDDocument doc = null;
        try {
            doc = PDDocument.load(inputFile);
            PDFTextStripper textStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            System.out.println(textStripper.getText(doc));
            PDGraphicsState graphicsState = null;

            PDDocumentInformation info = doc.getDocumentInformation();
            System.out.println("Page Count=" + doc.getNumberOfPages());
            System.out.println("Title=" + info.getTitle());
            System.out.println("Author=" + info.getAuthor());
            System.out.println("Subject=" + info.getSubject());
            System.out.println("Keywords=" + info.getKeywords());
            System.out.println("Creator=" + info.getCreator());
            System.out.println("Producer=" + info.getProducer());
            System.out.println("Creation Date=" + info.getCreationDate());
            System.out.println("Modification Date=" + info.getModificationDate());
            System.out.println("Trapped=" + info.getTrapped());
            System.out.println("isNeedToBeUpdate=" + info.getMetadataKeys());
            PDDocumentCatalog catalog = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
            PDMetadata metadata = catalog.getMetadata();
            List pages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
            for (int i = 0; i < pages.size(); i++) {
                PDPage page = (PDPage) pages.get(i);
                graphicsState = new PDGraphicsState(page.findCropBox());
                PDFont font = graphicsState.getTextState().getFont();
                if (font == null) {
                    font = new PDType1Font();
                }
                PDStream contents = page.getContents();
                PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(contents.getStream());
                parser.parse();
                List tokens = parser.getTokens();
                for (int j = 0; j < tokens.size(); j++) {
                    Object next = tokens.get(j);
                    if (next instanceof PDFOperator) {
                        PDFOperator op = (PDFOperator) next;
                        // Tj and TJ are the two operators that display
                        // strings in a PDF
                        if (op.getOperation().equals("Tj")) {
                            // Tj takes one operator and that is the string
                            // to display so lets update that operator
                            COSString previous = (COSString) tokens.get(j - 1);
                            String string = previous.getString(); // new String(previous.getBytes(), "ISO-8859-1");
                            string = string.replaceFirst(strToFind, message);
                            previous.reset();
                            System.out.println("p: " + string + " <=> " + previous.getHexString() + " <->" + new String(previous.getBytes(), "UTF-16BE")
                                    + " <->" + new String(previous.getBytes(), "ISO-8859-1"));
                            previous.append(string.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));// "test".getBytes());
                        } else if (op.getOperation().equals("TJ")) {
                            COSArray previous = (COSArray) tokens.get(j - 1);
                            for (int k = 0; k < previous.size(); k++) {
                                Object arrElement = previous.getObject(k);
                                if (arrElement instanceof COSString) {
                                    COSString cosString = (COSString) arrElement;
                                    String string = cosString.getString();
                                    String c = font.encode(cosString.getBytes(), 0, 1);
                                    System.out.println(c + " " + string + " <=> " + cosString.getHexString() + " <->"
                                            + new String(cosString.getBytes(), "UTF-16BE") + " <->" + new String(cosString.getBytes(), "ISO-8859-1"));
                                    string = string.replaceFirst(strToFind, message);
                                    cosString.reset();
                                    cosString.append(string.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                // now that the tokens are updated we will replace the
                // page content stream.
                PDStream updatedStream = new PDStream(doc);
                OutputStream out = updatedStream.createOutputStream();
                ContentStreamWriter tokenWriter = new ContentStreamWriter(out);
                tokenWriter.writeTokens(tokens);
                page.setContents(updatedStream);
            }
            doc.save(outputFile);
        } finally {
            if (doc != null) {
                doc.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting thing is that with the PDFTextStripper from pdfbox i can read the text fine. somehow this is reading it in a different way. at this moment i will look into the source of the PDFTextStripper to see what is happening there.

Comment: when stepping through the PDFTextStripper i see the font is used to encode the string. i try to add this code to the replace part but this results in a null font:
    PDFont font = graphicsState.getTextState().getFont();

Comment: The string arguments of **Tj** and **TJ** are not necessarily encoded in some ASCII related way as you have discovered already. On the other hand `graphicsState.getTextState().getFont()` is Only Meaningful while parsing. Unfortunately you don't show how you use it. So it's difficult to help you along further.

Comment: mkl thanks, i will add my full code which is a copy of an online example. it works only on some kind of pdf so if i could extend the example (and give back to the community) it would be great :)

Comment: Ah, ok, as used in your code, the `graphicsState.getTextState().getFont()` automatically is `null`; `PDGraphicsState` is a helper class in which, while parsing a content stream, you can store the current graphic state information. As you don't store anything in there, there is nothing to get from there. In essensce, while inspecting the content stream tokens, you have to also look for **Tf** operators which select the font to use for the next operations. For decoding the `COSString` e.g. look at `PDFStreamEngine.processEncodedText`.